# How do I include fragments of HTML within layouts?

Tags: html, templating

What's a simple way for me to write HTML files that have several "includes" that pull other HTML files into certain DIVs (which can in turn pull HTML files into certain of their DIVs, i.e. nesting)?

I would certainly want a CLI tool where I say "compile these files into plain old HTML" and it just works.

Comment: PHP is that kind of tool :) Also, read about [SSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of templating languages. Freemarker, google closure templates (soy), but if you want something simple and fast without lots of setup, try "Server Side Includes".

[Wikipedia Article On SSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)